# Center Position of ReportViewer - ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I use Report Viewer in visual studio 2010. I have 2 problems:
1. I can't center the table , it's align automatically to left.
2. I want to align the data into the table to right. how can I do that?

Thank you.
(this is my code for Report Viewer:)

[image: Example]

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div >
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
            Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
            WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt"  Height="800px" Width="100%" RightToLeft="YES">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="Report3.rdlc" > 
                <DataSources>
                    <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
                </DataSources>
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
            SelectMethod="GetData" 
            TypeName="Shemen.ta2014DataSetTableAdapters.SoftwareTableAdapter">
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to center the report itself, try:

```
<center>
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
                   WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt"  Height="800px" Width="100%" RightToLeft="YES">
  <LocalReport ReportPath="Report3.rdlc">
     <DataSources>
        <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
     </DataSources>
  </LocalReport>
 </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</center>
```

As for aligning the data, you would have to do that at the report level by selecting the column and setting the Horizontal Align property.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi , thanks , but the report actually on 100% of the page, you can see the toolbar above. it's part of the report. so I need to center only the table.

Comment: I didn't see that part. In this case, you can either remove the white space to the right within the report or you can center the table in it by adding equal amount of padding to the right & left.

Comment: This helped me, I set the control property SizeToReportContent="true" then wrapped the control in the <center> tags and this did exactly what I was looking for +1 fro me.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this issue and found out it can will solve by a few line of javascript. Enjoy

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 window.onload = function() {

        $('td#oReportCell', window.parent.frames[0].frames[1].document).next().remove();
        $('div#oReportDiv table', window.parent.frames[0].frames[1].document).attr("align", "center");
};

</script>
```